# base.html contains {% extends 'base.html' %}?

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm trying the django-cms tutorial,
There is something I don't understand [at the end of this part](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/support-3.0.x/introduction/plugins.html#install-the-polls-app) :

I have to add a template at **/mysite/templates/polls/base.html**. But this file has to begin with `{% extends 'base.html' %}`.
Is that normal? Is the file this line refers to an other **base.html** file? The one in the parent directory perhaps? I'm not sure at all.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: By the name I guess _this_ template will a **base template**, so it will be extended, it does not need extend from other template.

Comment: @Gocht yes, but there is another **base.html** in the parent directory (at **/mysite/templates/base.html**), and I guess this may be the default one. So I was wondering if this second one (at **/mysite/templates/polls/base.html**) could be a way to overwrite and improve the default one for the specific needs of the polls app. But for me, it's only an hypothesis until someone more experienced confirms this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extending from a `base.html` like that would suggest, like I do, that you have a `base.html` file at the root template directory of your project to handle the core markup;

```
{% load cms_tags menu_tags sekizai_tags cache i18n %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    {% block head %}{% endblock head %}
    <title>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="{% static 'project/external/jquery-1.11.2.min.js' %}"></script>

    {% render_block "css" %}
    {% render_block "js" %}

    {% block styles %}{% endblock styles %}
    {% block scripts %}{% endblock scripts %}

</head>
<body>
    {% cms_toolbar %}

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}

    {% block footer-scripts %}{% endblock footer-scripts %}
</body>
</html>
```

That way, when you setup templates in your apps you can start with a `base.html` for that app which may extend the base blocks for the head tag or elsewhere.

Usually I have a setup similar to `myproj/templates` and then app templates like `myproj/project/templates` and `myproj/app1/templates`. That first templates dir sits next to `manage.py` and I use the `project` dir to hold settings & any templates specific to that project like types of CMS page; `article.html` etc.

You don't have to extend `base.html` but if you don't, then you need to recreate all that markup again so by using this template model you'll be able to limit repeated markup.